# Script a Github file download using curl where filename AND path are variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards, curl, github

I needed to script the install of the ***Digital Ocean*** CLI " ***doctl*** " tool from ***Github*** using ***curl***, but there was a problem: The filename varied as it incorporated the version number- so hard-coding it would have required editing the script every time a new version was released, negating the entire point of automating it!

Just globbing with asterisks (or "stars" as some call them) in the path for variable directory & file names won't work.

The path I have to work with:

```
https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl/releases/download/v1.15.0/doctl-1.15.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

As you can see, even the directory the file lives in is variable by the version number.

I'll show the way I solved the problem, which might not be the most elegant solution.  If you have a tidier one, please share it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the `curl -sL` (to drop the progress bar and follow redirects), just like you were, but give it the URL for the latest linux-amd64 release:

```
curl -sL "$(curl -L -s https://api.github.com/repos/digitalocean/doctl/releases/latest |
  jq -r '.assets[] | select(.name | contains("-linux-amd64.tar.gz")).browser_download_url')" |
    tar -xzv
```

The inner command substitution asks the github API for the latest release of that repo; it then pipes it through `jq` to select the element whose name contains the string `-linux-amd64.tar.gz` and return back the download URL.

Comment: Your solution creates a circular dependency for RHEL users (which is most enterprise Linux users): in order to download the Digital Ocean " ***doctl*** " tool from Github, you must first download ***another*** Github tool: `jq` (not available in RHEL repos), which itself exists in an arbitrary, unpredictable path pointing to an S3 bucket than " ***doctl*** ".  But this path cannot be inferred, making it unscriptable so the install of " ***doctl*** " now would have a manually step installing `jq`.  If `jq` were in the default RHEL repo this would have been a great solution!

Answer (score 1):

I broke the path down into (3) parts:

1. **Non-Variable Base:** The part of the path which is 100% predictable and will not be subject to future change

`https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl/releases/download/`

2. **Variable DIRECTORY Name:** The name of the directory is the release number.  So although it's variable, it still predictable because it uses Semantic Versioning (https://semver.org/):

`v$(curl -s https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl/releases/ | grep -om 1 'doctl-.*-linux-amd64.tar.gz'|grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}')/`

The operation is to find the latest file and extract the version number from it. Since the " **v** " in the directory name is not part of the file name, it cannot be captured by a ***grep***. So I've just hard-coded in front of the self-populating variable

3. **Variable FILE Name:** The operation of the following expression extracts just the latest version (the " **m 1** " part) file name:

`$(curl -s https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl/releases/ | grep -om 1 'doctl-.*-linux-amd64.tar.gz')`

The whole ugly thingy looks as follows (with a " **| tar -xzv** " tacked on the end):

```
curl -sL https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl/releases/download/v$(curl -s https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl/releases/ | grep -om 1 'doctl-.*-linux-amd64.tar.gz'|grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}')/$(curl -s https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl/releases/ | grep -om 1 'doctl-.*-linux-amd64.tar.gz') | tar -xzv
```

This download will continue to succeed without any necessity to manually edit the script where the file & directory names change in future releases.

Again, might not be the most elegant solution, but solves the problem effectively.  If you have a better approach, please share!  HTH-