# Is it possible to download a file without knowing full name?

Tags: linux, wget, version, github

Sorry for asking what is probably a noob question.

I'm new to the GitHub and DevOps environments, and I've been tasked with automating some stuff.
I've found a project on GitHub that is still maintained, and in the future will receive new releases.

I would like to build a pipeline in which I will need to download from GitHub the latest exe version for my specific environment.

At the moment, they have the release packages in their git repo, under /releases/vX.y.z (where X, y and z are release versions) with several packages, named like:

- package.v1.2.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz (https://github.com/some-example-repo/download/v1.2.3/package.v1.2.3-linux-arm64.tar.gz)
- package.v1.2.3.linux-arm64.tar.gz (https://github.com/some-example-repo/download/v1.2.3/package.v1.2.3-linux-arm64.tar.gz)
- package.v1.2.3.windows-amd64.zip (https://github.com/some-example-repo/download/v1.2.3/package.v1.2.3-windows-amd64.zip)

etc.

Considering the fact that the versions will change in time, is there any way I could wget a specific package by using some sort of pattern?

Happily the link: https://github.com/some-example-repo/releases/latest redirects towards the latest version released and so I was thinking of something like:

```
wget https://github.com/some-example-repo/download/*????/package.V???*-linux-arm64.tar.gz
```

Thinking about it, now that I've put this down as a question, I think it would be impossible for wget to auto-complete the URL...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Script a Github file download using curl where filename AND path are variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/512409/script-a-github-file-download-using-curl-where-filename-and-path-are-variable)

Answer (score 18):

If you really want to always download the latest release, you should use [the GitHub API for this](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases#get-the-latest-release):

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/$USER/$REPO/releases/latest
```

This will return a JSON document describing the latest release, including all artifacts; you can filter the result with `jq`, *e.g.*

```
| jq -r '.assets[].browser_download_url'
```

to extract all the asset download URLs.

In practice however it’s often a bad idea to always download the latest release, because any breaking change could break your CI. You should instead download a specific release and upgrade as appropriate manually (perhaps with automation to test new releases and suggest the corresponding PR).

Comment: "because any breaking change could break your CI" - that and it will also be difficult to find out what environment specific builds/tests happened in (one will need to cross-reference build times with release schedules) leading to difficult to diagnose "works on my machine" bugs.

Comment: @user9123 I would expect the CI logs to keep a trace of what was downloaded, but if they don’t then yes, it could be complicated to determine what version was used after the fact.

Comment: Thanks @iBug, I can’t believe I got that wrong! I had the command in my terminal…